How to validate that one value is field is less than or equal to another using Cerberus?
I have a yaml config containing the float fields lower_quantile_probability and upper_quantile_probability. As the names suggest, the lower field should in fact be less than (or equal to) the upper field.
I see that Cerberus supports quite a number of validation options, including dependencies which appear to only support exact values. Correct me if I am wrong about that.
I would like to validate that order relations hold in this case. I want to validate that lower_quantile_probability >= upper_quantile_probability. Naturally the loaded yaml is just a Python dictionary so it is not at all difficult to write a separate function of my own.
Since I am using Cerberus for other forms of validation, I am hoping to have an all-Cerberus validation of my configuration rather than a mix of Cerberus and other validation code of that config. It is just a preference.
How to validate that one value is field is less than or equal to another using Cerberus?

Ah, I can write a custom validator!
